# How can I get parameter from dll function to python

Tags: python, c, ctypes, ida

I have a DLL file that contains this function

```
signed int __stdcall EncodeInit(unsigned int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4)
{
  signed int result; // eax@1

  result = 55;
  *(_DWORD *)a2 = (signed __int64)((double)a1 / 1.37 - 25.0 - 23.0 - 2.0 - 6.0);
  return result;
}
```

I am trying to call this function from Python:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll

# Load DLL into memory.

hllDll = cdll.LoadLibrary("E:\\sap mobile\\Bin32\\dbencod11.dll")
a1 = ctypes.c_int32(1)
print hllDll.EncodeInit(11, a1, 31, 4)
```

But I get an error:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000001
```

because `a1` is constant. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In the C code you use `a2` as an address, the address `1` is hardly ever valid. Not only that, on 64-bit systems a pointer is normally 64 bits, while `int` is usually still 32 bits, leading to even further problems.

Comment: I change to `a1 = ctypes.c_int64(1)` but don't help

Comment: Of course it won't help, the value of the second argument is *still* `1`, which is not a valid address.

Comment: @Joachim: Instead of just telling the OP what's wrong, why don't you tell them the right way to do it (or post an answer)?

Comment: Reading the [manual section about pointers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-pointers) might help. I'm not sure it will help though, since the argument actually isn't a pointer (why not?)

Comment: You should never use a literal value as an address.  If you need to pass an address use a1 = &variableName.  I don't know if Python and C use the same format or size for the value stored at &variableName, which may cause other issues.

Comment: I change to 
`hllDll = cdll.LoadLibrary("E:\\sap mobile\\Bin32\\dbencod11.dll")

pp = POINTER(ctypes.c_long)
print hllDll.EncodeInit(11, pp(ctypes.c_int()), 31, 4)` now get ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (16 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention